# Distinguishing between intensity image plots

Tags: image-processing, classification, image-analysis

I have a series of intensity images generated by varying different scatterer geometries. An example of variation observed by varying the aspect ratio of these geometries is shown below in the three images. The intensity values currently are normalized.

My aim is to quantitatively link the image features to the aspect ratio and identify which of those are sensitive to the image formation.  To me, this looks like an image-classification problem, but haven't been exposed to those before.

1. Are there any standard signal processing methodologies to investigate such problems?
2. How to decide on the threshold to estimate the spatial extent of the central bump along the x & y direction?

[image: Three different intensity images shown here]

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  Can you tell us what parts of the images are relevant?  Is it the total "area" of the central bump? Does knowing the $x$ and $y$ dimensions of the bump help?  Are the values all normalized?  (It looks like they are, but is the original data ranging from 0 to 1?).  Interesting problem!  Please add any extra info like this that you might have by [editing your question.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/84039/edit)

Comment: While we're asking about features -- it seems to go from a pretty good ellipse on the left, to something kidney or bean shaped on the right -- is this loss of ellipsoidal symmetry significant?

Comment: @TimWescott, Yes, this loss in the symmetry is due to the change in the scatterer geometry. The right-most image can be considered an extreme response.  One way, I am trying to explore now is to quantify the extent of the central bump in both directions to estimate the difference between each of the images.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main paths I can see here:

1. Deep Learning
   In case you have a lot of data you can just drop the images into a reasonably simple model and let it classify / regress to the values you want.
   It should work well if you have more than 1000 samples (Rough estimation).
2. Classic Computer Vision
   Extract some features.
   There many you can extract for this kind of data (For instance, look at [`regionprops()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html), think about the profile along some rows / columns).
   Push them through a gradient boosting based classifier ([XGBoost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost), [LightGBM](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM)). It should give good results even for moderate number of samples (~100).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are specifically looking for backprojection of single target scatterers, there are entire books on the topic.

"How to decide on the threshold to estimate the spatial extent of the central bump along the x & y direction?"

- plot in logarithmic scale find distance of 3 dB below height of main lobe